# Why are divs moving when the browser zooms out?

Tags: html, css

When I zoom out far on my browser, Chrome, the `info_table` moves down. Why does it do this? Also when added `overflow: auto;` to `section`, it also moves. What can I do?

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PbwS8/3/

**CSS**

```
*{  
    font-size:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
} 

body{
    width: 100%;
}

#info_table{
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 16px;
    border-spacing: 0px 0px;
}

#left{
    float:left;
    margin: 60px 0px;
}

#photo{
    float: left;
    width: 176px;
    height: 176px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#section{
    margin: 160px auto 0px;
    width: 675.2px;
    height: 320px;
    #overflow: auto;
    #border:1px solid black;
}

#choosephoto{
    width: 64px;
}

#submitwords{
    width: 72px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-left: 104px;
    #border:1px solid purple;
}


#wrapper{
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 3px 10px 5px #888888;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 48px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 960px;
    overflow: auto;
    background:white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="section">
            <body>
            </body>
            <form>
                <div id="left">
                    <div id="photo">

                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="file" id="choosephoto" name="uploadphoto"/>
                </div>
                <table id="info_table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:</td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Info:</td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><textarea></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button type="submit" id="submitwords">Update</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: [Lucky guess](http://jsfiddle.net/p44Zj/): maybe because of the 1px border and some rounding issues at various levels of zoom?

Comment: Looking in the developer console on Chrome shows that the border IS in fact being changed on `#photo` from 1.5015px to 2px, which is adding width to its container and (I assume) pushing your info box down.

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago Thanks, it was because of the border on photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for what is going on: It appears the browser is compensating for the zoom level by changing the width of the borders on `#photo`.

67% Zoom:

[image]

50% Zoom:

[image]

As for how to fix it? Unless being able to zoom like this is a badly needed, I wouldn't worry about it because it is a lot of work to make sure everything scales correctly.

Comment: Yup best answer thanks. I was not aware about this behavior in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `width` for `info_table` is set too wide for `section` `width`.

For example, reducing the width in `info_table` would alleviate this. So you could try replacing it with the following.

```
#info_table{
    float: left;
    width: 460px;
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 16px;
    border-spacing: 0px 0px;
}
```

Having said that, it would be better to read up on using a Grid System (like [960.gs](http://960.gs)).

Answer (score 0):

Why you have a body tag inside?
Your code is a mess, I re-write it for you [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fjFgL)